# java. lang. nullpointerexception: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.widget.CheckBox.isChecked()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I am trying to run this quiz app on my emulator and my phone, but every time I do, the app crashes on start and I get the following error:

```
java. lang. nullpointerexception: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.widget.CheckBox.isChecked()' on a null object reference
```

How can I fix that to make it so my app will run?

I appreciate any help.

**MainActivity code**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button btn;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

    CheckBox magicCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    magicCheckBox.isChecked();

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent i = new Intent("com.tutorial.quizapp.FIRSTQUIZ");
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
//noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

**xml file for Main Acitvity**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/start"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:padding="40dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**First Quiz java class**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;

public class FirstQuiz extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.quiz1);

    CheckBox magicCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    magicCheckBox.isChecked();

    RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new          RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId){
            if (checkedId == R.id.radio1) {
                setContentView(R.layout.final2);
            }
            else if (checkedId == R.id.radio2){
                setContentView(R.layout.final2);
            }
            else if (checkedId == R.id.radio3) {

                setContentView(R.layout.final1);

            } else if (checkedId == R.id.checkBox1) {

                setContentView(R.layout.final2);
            }
            else{
                setContentView(R.layout.final2);
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

**xml file for First Quiz**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/which_bowler_has_more_than_500_wicket_in_one_day_international"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"/>

<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_marginTop="116dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup">

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/shaun_pollock"
        android:id="@+id/radio1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/chaminda_vaas"
        android:id="@+id/radio2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/wasim_akram"
        android:id="@+id/radio3"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/zaheer_khan"
        android:id="@+id/radio4"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

</RadioGroup>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/submit"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_marginBottom="54dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

<CheckBox
    android:text="@string/magic_johnson"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginTop="87dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **cause** of the exception is here:

```
CheckBox magicCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
magicCheckBox.isChecked();
```

the `CheckBox` is invoked from `MainActivity.java` . However, the `CheckBox` exists in another Activity.

**FIX:**

Either move the `CheckBox`:

```
<CheckBox
android:text="@string/magic_johnson"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_marginTop="87dp"
android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

to `MainActivity`'s xml file.

OR

```
CheckBox magicCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
magicCheckBox.isChecked();
```

move this to `FirstQuiz.java` . That should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove these lines from your MainActivity

```
CheckBox magicCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
magicCheckBox.isChecked();
```

There is no checkBox present in the layout of the main Activity.

Else if your goal is to have a checkBox in the mainActivity, edit your main_activity.xml as follows:-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/start"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:padding="40dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Check Box" />

</RelativeLayout>
```